# Film photography, accidentally pressing the shutter button

Tags: exposure, shutter, 35mm

I am new to film photography. I have an old Praktica MTL3. I have properly loaded the film, and took some shots. Then I  accidentally clicked the shutter button, before winding the film. Will that ruin my last photography? There wasn't any sound, or anything... I am afraid that I will have two photographs on one exposure, or something like that.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry. As many cameras with curtain shutter Praktica MTL3 is constructed so that the shutter is set in a start position by winding the film. You can see it in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o6nmwk-3nfY) (between 17 and 20 secs)